# zeroMQ UnsatisfiedLinkError in java application

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, zeromq, unsatisfiedlinkerror

i have written a application that communicates via zeroMQ with another application. On my development machine running Ubuntu 13 is all well and working.

I do have zeroMQ 4.4.0 installed, also the jzmq java binding did compile without errors.

But on our testing/production server i get this. The application starts up and from requestInit() it tries to request it's configuration from the main configuration manager over zeroMQ.

```
bs@server-01:~/$ java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -jar /home/bs/opengraphchild/jar/opengraph.jar 5000 opengraph1
Params = 5000
Params = opengraph1
Starting Test service ...
Running
TestService.requestInit()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.nativeInit()V
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.nativeInit(Native Method)
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.<clinit>(ZMQ.java:521)
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Context.socket(ZMQ.java:451)
    at bs.core.service.GenericService.initZmqClient(GenericService.java:41)
    at bs.service.opengraph.OpenGraph.requestInit(OpenGraph.java:131)
    at bs.service.opengraph.OpenGraph.run(OpenGraph.java:62)
    at bs.service.opengraph.OpenGraphRunner.main(OpenGraphRunner.java:13)
```

I could not find anything relevant to my issue so i'm asking you guys. Please help :( [don't know if you need to see sourcecode, since it's working on my local machine, but i can add it]

output of `ldconfig -v | grep zmq`

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
    libzmq.so.3 -> libzmq.so.3.1.0
    libjzmq.so.0 -> libjzmq.so.0.0.0
    libzmq.so.1 -> libzmq.so.1
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied
```

output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcdf7c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f565a105000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5659ee8000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5659be7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5659827000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5659611000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f565a56b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5659314000)
```

output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/libjzmq.so`

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcf322000)
libzmq.so.3 => /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.3 (0x00007fe7499a8000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe7496a8000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe7492e7000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe7490df000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe748ec2000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe748cab000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe7489af000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe749e0c000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got to make it work on Windows, OS X and Ubuntu:

http://sourceforge.net/p/jalgo/code-0/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/org/aso/algo/messaging/bus/zmq/ZMQLoader.java#l17

The bus package also contains pub/sub establishment so feel free to refer to it.

Comment: The weird part is when i run `System.loadLibrary("jzmq");` it doesn't throw any error, not even UnsatisfiedLinkError as per javadoc. And yet when i try to initialise a REQ socket `zmqClientSocket = zmqClientContext.socket(ZMQ.REQ);` it fails.

Comment: I guess you also need to load zmq library in addition to jzmq? Also it would help if you can post some code.

Comment: i am loading both, and wich part of code would you need?

Comment: Nah ignore me on the code. Are you running the same version of Ubuntu on prod server and your desktop? What if you compile jzmq and libzmq on your testing server as a trial?

Comment: ok, tried to recompile the jzmq binding again and it magicaly works... oh man